# principal bundle and the associated bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $G\leq O(n)$ be a subgroup of orthogonal group. Let $\xi$ be a principal $G$-bundle. Let $\xi[\mathbb{R}^n]$ be the associated vector bundle.

If $\xi$ is not a trivial bundle, can we obtain that $\xi[\mathbb{R}^n]$ is not trivial?

If $\xi[\mathbb{R}^n]$ is a trivial bundle, can we obtain $\xi$ is a trivial bundle?

Comment: You can reconstruct the principal bundle as the bundle of orthogonal bases in the vector bundle, no?

Comment: Your two question are the same, by the way.